# How to label ellipse in latex? Why the label of my ellipse not appearing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to label each ellipse at the bottom of the ellipse. The ellipse appears in red but the label is not appearing. My code is attached as image below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}% for drawing ellipse

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}


\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%

\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!100,
                       inner sep=0pt, minimum width=5pt]%%%I need to keep this line to draw vertices in my diagram

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]%

\draw(-4.5,10)node[label={[yshift=-0.2cm, xshift=0cm]90:{$vertex 1$}}](v1){};

%3 ellipses

\draw (-9,6)  ellipse (2cm and 7cm) node at (0,-5)  {ELIPSE ONE}; 

\draw (-4.5,6) ellipse (2cm and 7cm);

\draw (0,6) ellipse (2cm and 7cm);


\end{tikzpicture}
}

{\captionof{figure}{FIGURE HOW TO LABEL ELLIPSE??}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![desired output]

FINAL CODE:

````
\begin{tikzpicture}[
E/.style = {ellipse, fill=none, draw=#1, 
            minimum height=7cm, minimum width=2cm},
E/.default=black
                        ]

\draw(-4.5,8)node[label={[yshift=-0.2cm, xshift=0cm]90:{$vertex 1$}}](v1){};

\node (e1) [E=red, label={[yshift=0.2cm, xshift=0cm]270:{ELLIPSE ONE}}] at (-9,6) {};

\node (e2) [E, label={[yshift=0.2cm, xshift=0cm]270:{ELLIPSE TWO}}] at (-4.5,6){};

\node (e3) [E] at (0,6) {};

\end{tikzpicture}```
````

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please never ever post images of code. You cannot expect others to retype your code in order to test it.

Comment: It is not clear, where label should be. Please add an sketch of what you expect to be generated by your code. Something like what do the following MWE: `\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)  ellipse (2cm and 7cm) node at (0,-5)  {ELIPSE ONE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: You should really post an MWE. You can attach a label to a `node`, not to a `path` like you are trying to do. In your case, you have to use a separate `node`, as explained in the comment by @Zarko.

Comment: What is an MWE?? i added the code above but it either publish as all in one line or as above ( I hit "enter" after every line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
E/.style = {ellipse, draw=#1, 
            minimum height=7cm, minimum width=2cm},
E/.default=black
                        ]
\node (e1) [E=red,
            label=below: ELIPSE ONE] {};
\node (e2) [E,right=of e1,
            label=below: ELIPSE TWO] {};
\node (e3) [E, right=of e2] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may liked that labels would use smaller font. In this case add to `tikzpicture` options:

```
every label/.append style = {font=<desired font size>}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko for the quick reply!! But could you add on to my code instead please? because when I try to combine yours and mine (which is much longer), 
Problem (1): the node for the labelling of ellipse appear BLACK (i need it invisible).. In particular, i need to keep the line saying "%%%I need to keep this line to draw vertices in my diagram"
Problem (2): Can we draw the ellipses based on the coordinates of the centre (-9,6), as in my code?
Thanks so much!! I appreciate your kind help

Comment: Dear @SphericalMoments, please make your question more clear in complete. Sorry, I cant insert my solution in your code since I suspect, that it is far to be complete (or what you afer). I only reproduce showed image, which as I understand know, doesn't represent what you like to have. BTW: on your image are not invisible ellipses ... Probably an sketch what you after, will help.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the problem, with your help of course!! Thanks much!!

Comment: @SphericalMoments, If you manage to find solution yourself, than wrote an answer and show avdience here, how.

Comment: @SphericalMoments, you can't only you can add ` before and after your code. Better writing is available in questions and answers ;-)

Comment: I needed to retain control of the positions of oval and labels. There is one possible way, which i obtained by modifying Zarko's code. I added my FINAL CODE in the question above, for whoever that needs it. Thanks all!!

Comment: @SphericalMoments, for formatting your code (frament) in question or answer, you should insert ``` before and after code. Than you not need to insert empty lines in code. Code will looks as is written (on gray paper).

Comment: Zarko, if i m using the ellipses for several diagram, can i define E. at the preamble instead of in every single figure? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: @SphericalMoments, put in ptemble `\tikzset{E/.style = {ellipse, draw=#1, 
            minimum height=7cm, minimum width=2cm},
E/.default=black}` and remove it from `tikzpicture` options

Comment: ok thank you Zarko!!